# converting $\max\{\ldots,\ldots\}$ function to a set of $\min\{\ldots,\ldots\}$ functions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Suppose $\max\{A,B\} = A$ if $A\geq B$ and $\max\{A,B\} = B$ if $A <B$. Similarly, $\min\{\}$ is defined.

We know that $\max\{A,B\} - A - B= - \min\{A,B\}$. Is it possible to write $\max\{A,B,C\} - A - B - C$ in terms of $\min\{\cdot\}$ functions ($\min\{A,B\}$, $\min\{A,C\}$, $\min\{B,C\}$, and $\min\{A,B,C\}$ are allowed)?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for your comment. I edited the question.

Comment: It's worth noting that your first identity is equivalent to $\min\{A,B\}+\max\{A,B\}=A+B$, which would naturally extend to $$\min\{A,B,C\}+\text{median}\{A,B,C\}+\max\{A,B,C\}=A+B+C$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\max\{A,B,C\}-A-B-C=\min\{A,B,C\}-\min\{A,B\}-\min\{A,C\}-\min\{B,C\}.$

Proof: By symmetry, we can assume $A\geq B\geq C$. Then
$$A-A-B-C=C-B-C-C.$$

Comment: Can we extend this to the case where we have $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ and we want to know about $\max\{A_1,\ldots, A_n\} - \sum_{i=1}^n A_i$?

Comment: Yes, this does extend, but it gets complicated fast. The key is that if you sum up the $\binom{n}{k}$ mins involving $k$ $A_i$'s we get exactly one copy of the $k$th smallest $A_i$ and a calculable number of the $k-1$ smaller $A_i$'s.